# White screen of death on admin and other dashboard pages

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have created a theme for the first time. but except the public area I cannot access admin by wp-admin. After changing he theme I saved redirected URL of admin which is this -->http://www.tennis-florida.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://www.tennis-florida.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1, this takes me to login page and allows me to login then again none of the images are loading as they were previously mapped to localhost and now When I am trying to upload anything or add or modify post after licking submit button it gives me blank white page and I have to click back in order to get back to dashboard. So all in all the theme is completely useless. What I am trying to achieve is I have to ship this theme to client as they are already seen it and so I have to make it work.

As I said I have figured it out that the problem is with the theme(For the record I have created the theme by following a YouTube tutorial)

I am sharing all my codes

functions.php

http://pastebin.com/yXNLuciE

index.php

http://pastebin.com/B9HXKzx8

page.php

http://pastebin.com/K9tzZF8e

header.php

http://pastebin.com/ERYhXCVq

footer.php

http://pastebin.com/PT6tZBmC

style.css

http://pastebin.com/HbTWp5p7

sidebar was not required so haven't added anything in there, sidebar.php is blank.

That's all the files I have created apart from folders for images and all.

I have tried adding

```
ini_set('display_errors', true) ;
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Even when I am trying to add a post and such with that another alternate admin link just after click publish wp shows blank page but the data is being added. to config and file and removing spaces in wp-config still no luck. Note: I cannot give up on theme as client has already seen this theme and I cannot provide another.

Note: This is a cross-post from wordpress.stackexchange.com as nobody answered this question.
I have already seen various other methods for solving this problem but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as nobody has answered it yet and I have found the solution.
Upon some research I found about white spacing in php files. All I did to fix the issue was deleting blank lines from bottom of `functions.php` file, strange fix but worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your PHP code which is what is causing the white screen.

SSH to the server and execute the files with the flag -l to check for syntax errors.

Comment: I don't have SSH access in my hosting service.

Comment: You can also install PHP locally.

Comment: I know its working fine, actually I have have developed the site locally.

Comment: If you know its working fine then why are you here asking for help?  Adjust the `error_reporting` level in PHP to `E_ALL` and see what the output is.

Comment: I meant to say its working fine on Localhost not on actual site, By the way I have fixed it now.